# Adreno 220 GLSL bug

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

We experience issue with GLSL alpha testing on *Sony Xperia S* phone with *Adreno 220* GPU. Device is running Android 4.0.4.

On *Adreno 200, Adreno 205, Adreno 225* as well as *Tegra2*, *Mali400* and *PowerVR* GPUs it works fine.

Shader code:

```
// vertex
            uniform highp mat4 uMVPMatrix;
            attribute highp vec4 aPosition;
            attribute highp vec2 aTextureCoord;
            varying mediump vec2 vTextureCoord;
            void main() {
              gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;
              vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
            } 

// fragment
            precision mediump float;
            varying mediump vec2 vTextureCoord;
            uniform sampler2D sTexture;
            uniform sampler2D sAlpha;
            uniform vec4 uBlendColor;
            void main() {
             vec4 base = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
             if(texture2D(sAlpha, vTextureCoord).r < 0.5){ discard; }
             else { gl_FragColor = base * uBlendColor; }
            }
```

Screenshot of bug:
[image: Buggy]

Correct result on other devices:
[image: Without bug]

Please advise what can cause such visual glitches, ways to find a cause and possible workarounds.

**EDIT**: The same bug confirmed for old stock ROMs of HTC Rezound. See my answer for more info.

Comment: good luck with that one. My workaround would be to exclude these devices in Google play

Comment: @rds No way. :)  I won't give up that easy - any visual glitch in my app must be eliminated. If I had a chance to debug on that device I'm pretty sure it was eliminated before publishing app to Google Play.

Comment: my only guess is that your alpha texture may have some values very close to 0.5, and due to rounding some values which you expect to be >= 0.5 are evaluating to < 0.5. Can you tell us more about your alpha texture? How it's generated, mini-/mag-nification filter, border wrap, etc.?

Comment: @SchighSchagh It is blacck-and-white (r==g==b) ETC1 compressed texture without mipmaps. Nearest min filter, linear mag filter. Borders are not clamped.

Comment: Give up! This could be a mobile driver specific issue, which may be impossible or not worthwhile to resolve. If you are writing a wallpaper application I don't see this as a killer feature and hence it is better to disable it.

Comment: I've tested it on co-worker's phone with Adreno 225 GPU - no bug. Anybody willing to test app on Adreno 220? I've modified shader logic and want to try it out on Adreno 220 (preferably, on Sony Xperia S phone)

Comment: I've got a whole bunch of XPeria devices, but none that uses the Adreno 220. I might be able to get hold of one next week when people are back from their xmas vacations. Is there an APK available for download somewhere?

Comment: @Michael Yes, you can get original app (with bug) from Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.androidworks.livewallpaperlotusfree and also with modified (and hopefully fixed) shader here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7197208/LiveWallpaperLotusFree-discard-last-no-else.apk (please excuse me for providing link to my app on Google Play, it is only for testing, don't treat this as advertisement)

Comment: I've now tested your modified version on an XPeria S running Android 4.0.4, and unfortunately the dark stripes are still there.

Comment: @Michael thank you for testing app. I will continue my research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked to test app on different firmwares on xda-developers. On some devices it works just fine while on another these is present this visual glitch.

So I conclude that it is related to some bug in OpenGL drivers which is fixed in certain non-stock ROMs.

**EDIT**: Confirmed it as a bug in old Qualcomm's Adreno 220 drivers. On *HTC Rezound* phone (also Adreno 220) with stock 4.0.3 ROM there was the same bug, and it was also present not only in my app but in some games too - missing certain lines or pixels on certain objects. After rooting and installing CM 4.1 bug disappeared.

Comment: Have you tried subtracting half-a-texel from your UV coords (a-la DirectX) ...?

Comment: Works fine on my 220 based HTC Sensation XE, btw.

Comment: @Goz All code of my shaders is provided in question. I've also tried 3 different modifications of fragment shader logic but to no avail.

Comment: The DirectX UV coord "fix" is usually performed from C/C++ code and nowt to do with GLSL ...